# What is standard app lexicon?

Tags: user-expectation, copywriting

I'm developing a user manual for an app that controls some hardware. I need to walk the user through using the app to get it set up, adjust settings, and for general use.

What is the standard app lexicon when referring to the user interacting with the app?

Here's some that come to mind...

**Touch (A):**

- Touch
- Tap
- Press
- Select

**Screen (B):**

- Screen
- Page
- App

In short, I'm trying to say:

> To set this up later, _____ (A) the "Skip" button in/on top right of the _____ (B) .

Comment: I'd probably look to some of the big players for this one. Have you checked out any published design guidelines from, for example, Google, Apple, or Microsoft?

Answer (score 4):

Apple's Human Interface Guidelines ([link](https://developer.apple.com/design/human-interface-guidelines/ios)) uses "tap" for interacting with a touchscreen device like the iPhone and "screen" or "app screen" when referring to what you are tapping.

So, your sentence would read: "To set this up later, tap the "Skip" button on the top right of the screen"

Answer (score 1):

"press"

Because "longpress" on Android is the right way to describe a longpress (longtouch is not a thing).

"screen"

Given an app can manifest in ways beyond the screen, e.g. Android apps can have companion devices linked over bluetooth, being specific as to where to touch can help avoid ambiguity.

Re: "select" you may use that in place of "touch" at a higher-level of abstraction, where the touch event effectively selects an option from a set.

Comment: Appears to be operating system specific. Hmm, I'll dig into what Android guidelines say.